# how to get output from procedure in sql server 2014 in php?

Tags: php, sql-server-2014

I have output of procedure but i dont know how to display it..

this is my code

```
$ip_jobprofilename = (isset($_POST['JobProfileName']) && $_POST['JobProfileName'] != "") ? $_POST['JobProfileName'] : NULL ;  
$ip_sessionid = $_SESSION['userid']; 
$op_jobprofileid = (int)NULL;
$op_msg = (string)NULL; 

$jobpro_ins_pro = " {call sc.spJobProfile_I(?, ?, ?, ?)} " ;
$param = array( 
    array($ip_jobprofilename, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($ip_sessionid, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($op_jobprofileid, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
    array($op_msg, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
); 

$exec_pro = sqlsrv_query($conn, $jobpro_ins_pro, $param);

if($exec_pro === false)
{  
    $errors = sqlsrv_errors();
}
else
{   
    echo "ErrMessage = ".$op_msg;
    // echo $op_msg;  exit;
}
```

Comment: Tried [one of the examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-fetch-array-examples)?

Comment: In other words, try fetching the `$exec_pro` query results.

Comment: fetching is not working, in the above code i am using insert stored procedure..